# Saving UIImage from UIbutton to object UIImage to copy to other UIButtons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, uiimage

What I basically want to do us have a `UIImage` global object, I then want to have multiple `UIButton`s with background images that if selected is saved to the global `UIImage`.

I then want to take that saved image from the selected button and use it to set other `UIButton`s background images.

How can I do this?

Comment: How have you tried?  Please post some sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are setting background image to `UIButton` then you can get it using

**setImage**

```
[yourBtn setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**getImage**

```
UIImage *image=[yourBtn backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**Or**

If you are setting image (using `setImage`)to your `UIButton` then

```
UIImage *image=yourBtn.imageView.image;
```

Comment: your welcome...you can accept answer if your problem is solved..or if you have any doubt then feel free to ask..:)

Answer (score 1):

Use your AppDelegate class for the app-global UIImage.

Then, when you want to set this UIImage as the background on UIButtons, use the method:

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
```

[API Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setBackgroundImage%3aforState%3a)